# Как узнать координаты елемента относительно видимой части экрана при помощи jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как узнать координаты елемента относительно видимой части экрана при помощи jquery.
Нужна jquery альтернатива getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: а чем указанный метод не угодил?

Comment: Мне нужен именно jquery метод

Comment: всё ещё [актуально](https://habr.com/ru/post/240083/)

Comment: @daobs у Вас железная аргументация